# Do some, all, or no Mahayanists claim that we are all "bodhisattvas"?

Tags: mahayana, bodhisattva

Do some, all, or no Mahayanists claim that we are all "bodhisattvas"? Obviously, those influenced by the Lotus sutra claim that we are all -- at least potentially -- Buddhas. But I'm unclear about the word "bodhisattva", whether anyone at all can rightfully claim they are a bodhisattva.

For example, I think I'm aware of some ch'an Buddhists, which was deeply influenced by the 'one vehicle', saying that we progress through stages, only being bodhisattvas after abandoning the three vehicles. But perhaps this is skilful means, and not at all the case?

Answer (score 2):

As i understand it they think that those who do a ceremonial ritual of taking the Bodhisatta vows become Bodhisattas. I may be wrong tho.

Comment: that would make sense, at least. thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to my knowledge, to become a bodhisattvas, the person should obtain due certainty of being a bodhisattvas from a Buddha with the effect of Karma. We could identify this fact by considering the story behind Maithree bodhisattvas.